# optimising linq queries to incres

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have the the below linq queries searching a the same data table and was wondering if it would be possible to make one search and do the below for loops to add data to to the same variables so that it can make the system faster.

```
var sort = configurationData.AsEnumerable().Where(sorts => sorts.Field<String>("QuestionStartText") == question &&
    sorts.Field<String>("slideNo") == Convert.ToString(slideNumber) )
             .Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("SortByColumn")).Distinct().AsParallel();

var rowNeedAfterSort = configurationData.AsEnumerable().Where(sorts => sorts.Field<String>("QuestionStartText") == question &&
    sorts.Field<String>("slideNo") == Convert.ToString(slideNumber))
                 .Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("NoOfRows")).Distinct().AsParallel();

var indexs = configurationData.AsEnumerable().Where(sorts => sorts.Field<String>("QuestionStartText") == question &&
    sorts.Field<String>("slideNo") == Convert.ToString(slideNumber))
                 .Select(sorted => sorted.Field<String>("ColumnInExcel")).Distinct().AsParallel();

int p = 0;
int chartValue = 0;

foreach (string inedcies in indexs)
{
    if (inedcies != null)
    {
        if (!inedcies.ToUpper().Equals("NULL"))
        {

            if (inedcies.Contains(','))
            {
                Array.Clear(valuesUsed, 0, valuesUsed.Length);
                string[] index = inedcies.Split(',');
                foreach (string a in index)
                {
                    valuesUsed[p] = Convert.ToInt32(a);
                    p++;
                }
            }
            else if (inedcies.Equals("7"))
            {
                Array.Clear(valuesUsed, 0, valuesUsed.Length);
                valuesUsed[p] = Convert.ToInt32(inedcies);
            }
            else
            {
                chartValue = Convert.ToInt32(inedcies);
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach (string sortedint in sort)
{
    if (sortedint != null)
    {
        if (!sortedint.ToUpper().Equals("NULL"))
        {
            SortData2(sortedint);
            sortedData = "true";
        }
    }
}

foreach (string rows in rowNeedAfterSort)
{
    if (rows != null)
    {
        if (!rows.ToUpper().Equals("NULL"))
        {
            string[] values = rows.Split(' ');
            rowCount = Convert.ToInt32(values[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you clean up the below codesmell you will be able to see how/where you can take out the foreach loops.

```
   foreach (string a in index)
        {
            valuesUsed[p] = Convert.ToInt32(a);
            p++;
        }
```

what assurances do we have that `index.length < valuesUsed.length` ?

```
Foreach (x in y)
{ 
if (x != null)
    {
     do something
    }
}
```

More readable. You also do not need to check if an element is null in a foreach loop. The properties of the element may need to be checked, but not the element itself.

```
y.Foreach(x => do what you need here)
```